# Pass Managed Function Pointer As Unmanaged Callback

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, c++-cli, unmanaged

I am attempting to pass a managed function pointer `void (*)(void *)` to my unmanaged library.  My unmanaged library calls this callback with a pointer to a frame of data protected by a CriticalSection.  While the managed callback is running, nothing else can modify the frame of data due to the Critical Section.  However, I am getting Access Violations and Heap Corruptions just by entering the callback.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention.  The `StartStreaming()` steals the thread it manages.  Furthermore, it creates a separate thread for dispatching new data to the given callback.  The callback is called in this separate thread.

So far I have done the follow:

```
//Start Streaming
streaming_thread_ = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&Form1::WorkerThreadFunc));
streaming_thread_->Start();
```

Where:

```
extern "C" {
#include "libavcodec\avcodec.h"
#include "libavutil\avutil.h"
}

namespace TEST_OCU {

delegate void myCallbackDelegate(void * usr_data); //Declare a delegate for my unmanaged code

public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    public:

    static void WorkerThreadFunc()
    {
        myCallbackDelegate^ del = gcnew myCallbackDelegate(&Form1::frame_callback);

        MessageBox::Show("Starting to Streaming", "Streaming Info");
        if(rtsp_connection_ != NULL)
            rtsp_connection_->StartStreaming();
            //rtsp_connection_->StartStreaming((void (*)(void *)) System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(del).ToPointer() );
        MessageBox::Show("Done Streaming", "Streaming Info");
    }

    static void __cdecl frame_callback(void * frame)
    {
        AVFrame * casted_frame = (AVFrame *)frame;
    }

private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
    {
        if(rtsp_connection_ == NULL)
            rtsp_connection_ = new NeyaSystems::RTSPConnection("rtsp://url");
    }

    private: static RTSPConnection * rtsp_connection_ = NULL;
}
}
```

- I've omitted a lot of pointless code...
- `StartStreaming` defaults to a NULL pointer, in this case I get no corruption
- `StartStreaming` with the delegated function pointer causes heap corruption
- `RTSPConnection` is implemented in native C++ and contains C calls as well (libavcodec)
- `RTSPConnection` contains two threads, communication and frame dispatch thread (calls the managed callback)

Could anyone give me a breadcrumb?  Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: not a problem with cross-thread calls.  If the unmanaged caller expects to call a __cdecl function, then you have to decorate the delegate type with an UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute attribute.

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

[UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention::Cdecl)] 
delegate void myCallbackDelegate(void * usr_data);
```

Comment: Hey Monroe, do you mean WorkerThreadFunc?  In my real call, I have GUI calls in my frame_callback and I do use `BeginInvoke` on an `Form::Update()` delegate.

Comment: @Constantin I've found through experience that the best place to do the BeginInvoke would be in the Form instance itself... it has the best context to know if the calling thread is the UI thread or not.

Comment: Ah, I see now that you aren't calling any UI functions in frame_callback; my bad.  Perhaps removing the __cdecl?

Comment: I'm still a little confused.  Nothing is done in the GUI thread.  Notice that that `Form1::WorkerThreadFunc` is started in its own thread.  Furthermore, this thread is taken over by `StartStreaming()` (an unmanaged c++ call)

Comment: [UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
delegate void myCallbackDelegate(void * usr_data);

Comment: OOoo, this is good! Let me try it out, having difficulty compiling... one sec

Comment: Aweessomme, no memory leaks no corruption.  Perfect.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
 myCallbackDelegate^ del = gcnew myCallbackDelegate(&Form1::frame_callback);
```

That declares the delegate as a local variable in your method.  Local variables are subject to garbage collection right after the last statement that uses them.  You are correctly using Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate() but that's not sufficient to make the garbage collector understand that the delegate is in use, it cannot track references in native code.  So the next garbage collection taking place during or after the StartStreaming() call is going to destroy the delegate.  And your callback will bomb.

It isn't clear exactly when callbacks stop being made.  At the very least you need to put GC::KeepAlive(del); after the StartStreaming() call.  If callbacks are made after the WorkerThreadFunc() stops running, likely considering the "Start" in the method call, you must keep the delegate object alive longer by, say, storing it as a field in your form class.  Possible declared static to keep it alive until program termination.

Comment: Hi Hans, the StartStreaming() call is blocking ... due to the library I use (I hate it but I don't have a say in the matter.)  Should I still include the KeepAlive call before the StartStreaming call?

Comment: Then you need the GC::KeepAlive() call to keep the delegate object alive while StartStreaming is running.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure that's true in this case.  Because the function `WorkerThreadFunc()` stays in scope for the duration of the unmanaged call to `StartStreaming()`, the local reference to `myCallbackDelegate` will stay rooted.  If `WorkerThreadFunc()` were to return before `StartStreaming()` completes, then you are, of course, correct.