# libcurl is apparently crashing the application

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli, libcurl

```
Config:
Windows 11 x64
Visual Studio Project: CLR Empty Project (.NET Framework)
.NET Framework: 4.6.2
libcurl: curl-7.83.1 windows build (libcurl-vc-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-schannel)
Project architecture: Release x86
```

Well, I'm trying to report a download progress in my `Windows Forms` application using `libcurl` however there are some issues with a pointer from the managed into the unmanaged code apparently when dealing with `System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`, here's my files:

Program.cpp:

```
#include "MyForm.h"
[System::STAThread]
int main(array<System::String^>^ args) {
    try {
        System::Windows::Forms::Application::SetUnhandledExceptionMode(System::Windows::Forms::UnhandledExceptionMode::ThrowException);
        System::Windows::Forms::Application::EnableVisualStyles();
        System::Windows::Forms::Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        DownloadProgressTest::MyForm updater;
        System::Windows::Forms::Application::Run(% updater);
        return 0;
    }
    catch (System::Exception^ exception) {
        System::Console::WriteLine(exception->ToString());
        return -1;
    }
}
```

downloader.h:

```
#pragma once
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include <string>
class Downloader final {
public:
    static size_t writeData(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE* stream) {
        size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
        return written;
    }

    static void download(System::Delegate^ progressFunction) {
        CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) {
            const char* URL = "https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/8e396c75-4d0d-41d3-aea8-848babc2736a/80b431456d8866ebe053eb8b81a168b3/ndp462-kb3151800-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe";
            const wchar_t* fileName = L"D:\\Backup\\Downloads\\dotnet462.exe";
            FILE* fp;
            _wfopen_s(&fp, fileName, L"wb");
            if (fp) {
                System::IntPtr progressFunctionPointer = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(progressFunction);

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl");
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeData);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progressFunctionPointer);

                CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl); // This line crashes the application.

                if (res == CURLE_OK) {
                    System::Console::WriteLine("Download completed.");
                }
                else {
                    System::Console::WriteLine("Couldn't download file.");
                }

                std::fclose(fp);
            }
            else {
                System::Console::WriteLine("Couldn't open file.");
            }

            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        else {
            System::Console::WriteLine("Couldn't initialize curl.");
        }
    }
};
```

MyForm.h (relevant part only):

```
public: delegate int DelegateProgressChanged(void* clientPointer, double totalToDownload, double nowDownloaded, double totalToUpload, double nowUploaded);

public: int progressChanged(void* clientPointer, double totalToDownload, double nowDownloaded, double totalToUpload, double nowUploaded) {
    double percentage = (nowDownloaded / totalToDownload) * 100;
    System::Console::WriteLine("I will print this before application crashes.");
    return 0;
}

public: System::Void startDownload() {
    Downloader::download(gcnew DelegateProgressChanged(this, &MyForm::progressChanged));
}

public: System::Void MyForm_Shown(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    System::Threading::Tasks::Task::Run(gcnew System::Action(this, &MyForm::startDownload));
}
```

As you can see on the following libcurl documentation my delegate and `progressChanged` functions fit the function signature: [libcurl documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION.html).

My code works fine when providing a pointer directly from an unmanaged function, however I need to report the progress in a `System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar` from my application so that's why I need it to be managed.

It creates the download file in the specified directory (incomplete file though), prints out the **"I will print this before application crashes."** then application gets crashed at the line `CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);` and I couldn't catch any exception not even in the Debug build but the following error from Visual Studio is displayed:

```
Exception thrown at 0x38AD0002 in DownloadProgressTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x38AD0002.

Original Location: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll
```

What's going on here? Am I dealing in the wrong way with pointers? Is there a workaround for this?

***EDIT***

Thanks john for his comment, I managed to fix the problem but partially, now I'm getting the following exception when updating my `System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar`:

```
percentage value is: -2147483648
percentage value is: -2147483648
percentage value is: -2147483648
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value of '-2147483648' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
Parameter name: Value
   at System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.set_Value(Int32 value)
   at DownloadProgressTest.MyForm.BeginInvokeMeProgressChanged(Int32 percentage) in C:\Users\censored\source\repos\DownloadProgressTest\DownloadProgressTest\MyForm.h:line 94
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at main(String[] args) in C:\Users\censored\source\repos\DownloadProgressTest\DownloadProgressTest\Program.cpp:line 9
```

Since the progress function is inside a `System::Threading::Tasks::Task` this is how I'm updating the progress bar:

```
public: System::Void BeginInvokeMeProgressChanged(int percentage) {
    this->progressBar1->Value = percentage;
    this->label1->Text = "Download progress: " + percentage + "%";
}
public: int progressChanged(void* clientPointer, double totalToDownload, double nowDownloaded, double totalToUpload, double nowUploaded) {
    int percentage = (int)((nowDownloaded / totalToDownload) * 100);
    System::Console::WriteLine("percentage value is: " + percentage);
    this->BeginInvoke(gcnew System::Action<int>(this, &MyForm::BeginInvokeMeProgressChanged), percentage);
    return 0;
}
```

It looks like `BeginInvoke` messes up the `percentage` variable inside the `libcurl` unmanaged progress function, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298225/pass-managed-function-pointer-as-unmanaged-callback

Comment: Hi @john thanks for your comment because of you I fixed the problem but partially, can you take a look at it again?

Comment: I don't know enough C# to really help. But googling around seemed to find several relevant hits.

Comment: @john It's not C# by the way, it's C++ CLI. I figured out a workaround thank you john.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As john mentioned on his comment, I fixed it up by doing it at the top of my MyForm.h file:

```
[System::Runtime::InteropServices::UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute(System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention::Cdecl)]
delegate int DelegateProgressChanged(void* clientPointer, double totalToDownload, double nowDownloaded, double totalToUpload, double nowUploaded);
```

then declaring that delegate as a member in order to avoid it gets garbage collected hence an exception is thrown:

```
private: DelegateProgressChanged^ delegateProgressChanged;
```

And to fix up the messed up percentage value I simply did the following:

```
public: int progressChanged(void* clientPointer, double totalToDownload, double nowDownloaded, double totalToUpload, double nowUploaded) {
    if (nowDownloaded > 0 && totalToDownload > 0) {
        int percentage = (int)((nowDownloaded / totalToDownload) * 100);
        this->BeginInvoke(gcnew System::Action<int>(this, &MyForm::BeginInvokeMeProgressChanged), percentage);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above solution fixes everything up, thank you.